# There is no app mode on my Facebook developer page

Tags: flutter, dart, facebook, google-developers-console

There is no app mode on my Facebook developer page, I would like to switch to live to avoid error like this "App not activate. This app is not accessible right now and the app developer is aware of the issue. You will be able to log in when then app is reactivated"

I just want to fix the "App not activate" error even though I have a developer account and I added a privacy policy URL it still doesn't work.